# Laravel Query Builder Join results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a join in laravel 5.1 and it works fine, however I am getting back an array with each result of my join. Is there a way I can get the results back with the join results a nested array inside of my main select query, or would this have to be something I do in PHP after getting the results back?

```
$single = $this->db->table($this->table)
            ->leftJoin("ootd_clothing", "ootd_clothing.ootd_id", "=" ,"$this->table.id")
            ->leftJoin("users", "users.id", "=", "$this->table.user_id")
            ->where("$this->table.slug", "=", $slug)
            ->select("$this->table.name AS ootd_name", "$this->table.image_path", "$this->table.slug", "$this->table.description", "users.name AS user_name", "ootd_clothing.item", "ootd_clothing.brand")
            ->get();
```

Result I'm getting:

```
array:5 [▼
0 => {#158 ▶}
1 => {#159 ▶}
2 => {#160 ▶}
3 => {#161 ▶}
4 => {#162 ▶}
]
```

Result I would like:

```
array:1 [
  'id': 1, 
  'joinResults':array:5 [▼
     0 => {#158 ▶}
     1 => {#159 ▶}
     2 => {#160 ▶}
     3 => {#161 ▶}
     4 => {#162 ▶}
 ]
]
```

Comment: I do not think this is possible with a single query, because database does not work that way, it returns a list of matched rows and not a multilevel array.

Comment: You could use Laravels `Eloquent::with()` to load related data in a separate query, this way you will only use 2 queries, first to retrieve parent and second for related data

Comment: May I ask why you would want results like that? You're making it hard I thought you just want to get results.